# How to know the new names that multiple repositories have been renamed to?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I have an application that records the names of some GitHub repositories in database. Take the following 3 repos for example.

1. https://github.com/zhangkun-Jser/react-experience
2. https://github.com/zhangkun-Jser/vue-plug
3. https://github.com/hsluoyz/casbin

But the issue is the repos I recorded may be renamed. For example, the above three repos have been respectively renamed to:

1. https://github.com/zhangkun-Jser/react-kit
2. https://github.com/zhangkun-Jser/FE-plugs
3. https://github.com/casbin/casbin

I want to write some code to actively update any old repo names to new repo names in my database. For example, update `zhangkun-Jser/react-experience` to `zhangkun-Jser/react-kit`.

I know I can use `GitHub V3 API` to get the repository info for every repo and then get the new name. But this requires to send a request for every repo. My question is `if there is any method to get the new names for a list of repos in one request`?

**Note**: The repos can be from different owners, like in the example.

I tried to use the `GraphQL API v4` but I didn't know how to get the info of a list of repos. And the V4 API seems not to recognize the old names. For example, if I send the following request:

```
{
  repository(owner: "zhangkun-Jser" name: "react-experience") {
    name
    id
  }
}
```

The response is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Could not resolve to a Repository with the name 'react-experience'.",
      "type": "NOT_FOUND",
      "path": [
        "repository"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the Node ID of the Repository and look up the Node by ID:

```
query { 
  repository (owner:"osowskit", name:"about") { 
    id
  },
  node(id:"MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk1NjE2NzA2OQ") {
  ... on Repository {
      id,
      name,
      nameWithOwner
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's say I have stored the node ids of multiple repos (from multiple users). How to query their latest names in one GraphQL request? If I have to use multiple requests, there is no difference with GitHub V3 API.

Comment: I apologize for missing that part of the question. The long-term strategy is to store node IDs instead of repo names to avoid detecting name changes. However, you can look up multiple sets of data by using an [Alias](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases). 

```
repo1: repository (...) {},
repo2: repository (...) {}
```